# datatables unir campos

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable

Estoy tratando de unir dos campos en una sola columna de un DataTable, pero no funciona, sugerencias? aqui mi codigo

```
var listar = function(){
        var table = $("#dt_cliente").DataTable({
            "destroy":true,
            "order": [2,'desc'],
            "ajax":{
                "method":"POST",
                "url":"listar.php"
            },
            "columns":[ 
            {"data":"codigo"},
            {"data":"numero"},
            {"render": 
                function ( data, type, row ) {
                    return (row[3] + ' ' + row[4]);
            }
            },                  
            {"data":"tipo"},
```

El resultado que obtengo en el campo es :undefined undefined

Answer (score 3):

logre hacerlo funcionar de la sgte manera

```
        columns: [
        { data: null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
            // Combinar campos
            return data.first_name+' '+data.last_name;
        } },
```

Comment: luego de buscar mucho, finalmente me funciona, mil gracias por compartir.

Comment: Aunque ya haya pasado mucho tiempo, ¡no olvides aceptar tu respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con esto para unir varios campos de una tabla en una columna datatable :

```
{"render":
    function ( data, type, row ) {
        return (row["nombre"]+ ' ' + row["apellido"]+ ' ' + row["segundo_apellido"]);
        }
    },
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente qué hace este código. Lee [answer].